# XSLT: compare letters used as grouping key

Tags: xslt, xpath, collation, xslt-2.0

I'd like to group elements by the first letter, but some different letters should be considered equal: A and Ä (and a and ä) should all be the same.

Source:

```
<root>
  <entry name="Aa" />
  <entry name="Ab" />
  <entry name="Äa" />
  <entry name="Ac" />
  <entry name="Ba" />
</root>
```

The transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="upper-case(substring(@name,1,1))">
        <key><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></key>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result now:

```
<root>
   <key>A</key>
   <key>Ä</key>
   <key>B</key>
</root>
```

The result as I'd like it to have:

```
<root>
   <key>A</key>
   <key>B</key>
</root>
```

Where all entries except for "Bb" should be in the first group.

I assume the key to success is making the `group-by()` function correct to treat a,A,ä and Ä equal (this is true for some German sorting/ordering rules). But I have not found an xpath function that could handle that.

Comment: I have found one solution, but is there a more clever / cleaner one? `substring(normalize-unicode(upper-case(@name),'NFD'),1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `translate(substring(@name,1,1), 'Ä', 'A')`?

Comment: Looks good, but there must be a more simple solution without giving more character classes (Ü->U and Ö->O and ß -> s)

Comment: @Patrick: just put them together like `translate(substring(@name,1,1), 'ÄßÜÖ', 'ASUO')`

Comment: Embarrassing, I should have looked into the documentation. You're right, of course. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible approaches:

(a) use the collation attribute of xsl:for-each-group, specifying a collation that has the right comparison semantics. Unfortunately this will be dependent on your XSLT processor. For Saxon, for example, you might use

```
http://saxon.sf.net/collation?lang=de;ignore-case=yes;ignore-modifiers=yes
```

as described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/collation.xml

(b) the alternative is to "do it yourself" as most of the answers here have been recommending: that is, write some function which normalizes case and strips accents before doing the grouping. Calling lower-case() or upper-case() isn't perfect for normalizing case, though upper-case() is probably OK for German where the main problem is to make "ß" and "ss" group together. Getting rid of accents can be done by using normalize-unicode() to normalize to Unicode decomposed normal form, and then replace() to eliminate characters in category \p{Lm}.

I would recommend using collations.